# Does CPU architecture influence and define OS design?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

I am currently reading a manual dedicated to OS development. The first part of the book describes how to write a boot sector, which is followed by a more dense text devoted to kernel development. Also, I have not been questioning myself a lot about the code structure until I have encountered following instruction sequence:

```
lgdt; load global descriptor table
mov eax, cr0; switch adressing mode and paging control via cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax
```

Actually, I have always been persuaded that all this stuff related to memory paging, the concept of kernel, protection rings was just a fancy idea born somewhere deep in some OS designer's mind. However, the existence of these instructions shows that GDT and everything that goes together is dictated by the CPU design. So, basically, according to my understanding, there is no conceptual difference between *nix and Windows (I mean mainstream OS). If my premise is correct, I would like to ask several questions.

1) If OS is written accordingly to CPU architecture, ie following the same design rules established since the dawn of ages, why OS developer job openings are often tagged as "R&D engineering"? Besides using 64-bit registers, what kind of novelty can be introduced into OS development?

2) Is there any way to build an OS which doesn't have any of aforementioned features and still can use all the capacities of CPU, ie not to be restricted to 16-bit instruction set? What about Kolibri OS or Menuet OS? Besides being written on ASM, do these OS conceptually differ from MS Windowes or *nix? Do they also need to establish GDT, enter protected mode, etc?

3) Who influences who? Gates calls to Intel designers and says he needs a GDT feature in CPU? Or electrical engineers from Intel call Gates and point him that he has no choice but have to live all his life with GDT and paging? In general how do CPU designers interact with software community?

Comment: `Does CPU architecture influences OS design?` -- **Why wouldn't it?**  If your OS can benefit from a particular CPU feature, you would use it, wouldn't you?  But you also wouldn't tie yourself to a specific processor, so perhaps you would implement feature detection.

Comment: As to your question, you need to focus it onto a specific software development problem you are currently having.  From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face... Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."*

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I am targeting OS development job, that's why have to read a lot of textbooks. But it seems that all OS will look the same. That is why I would like to know whether it is worthy to learn how to develop an OS from the scratch.

Comment: Your 1) makes no sense.  Why do people keep writing different user-space programs and adding new features to them, even though the hardware they run on will be the same.  So no, an OS isn't the same thing as an ISA, it's software that runs on an ISA.

Comment: If your target is an OS development job, then writing an OS (even a simple one) makes a lot of sense.  That's how the rest of us sharpen our skills.

Comment: Is the stuff in 2) about "call [Bill] Gates" a pun on [x86 call gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_gate_(Intel))?  (A type of GDT entry that can change privilege level when you do a `call far` to that code segment, letting it work like an `int` instruction for system calls.  https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls#Call_Gates_.28Intel.29)  Intended or not, it was funny.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, in this case why is it called a "new" OS? Why not simply issue a patch or something like this?

Comment: It's not called a new OS.  What are you talking about?  A new release / new *version* of an existing OS is *not* a "new OS" in this sense.  It's like saying Firefox 51 is a "new program" compared to Firefox version 50.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: *most* OS dev jobs will be working on an existing OS, not inventing one from scrach.  You're probably better off reading some about how existing open-source OSes are designed before (and maybe instead of) trying to write your own.  Concepts like what a context switch is are probably more easily learned from seeing how Linux does it than figuring out even the concept on your own.  Most jobs won't involve reimplementing or modifying that low-level stuff; you have to understand the concept but you'll really be working on code for some driver or kernel algorithm, I'd guess.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I was not clear in my answer. For me, OS developer is a kind of research job who has to dig deep into CPU instruction set and other hardware and then invent something revolutionary new. But it seems that all the steps in OS development look the same. Yes, indeed, the practice will sharpen my skills, but it will be the same as if I will learn some complicated, but still very well known algorithm.

Comment: Or to put it another way, writing an OS from scratch will involve mostly writing stuff that's unlikely to change in existing mainstream OSes.  Useful to understand how it works, but you can probably get there more quickly by reading about it, instead of trying to write a kernel and finding out along the way what that even means, and what things you need to implement.

Comment: 3) CPU architect is the job description you're talking about there.  It's apparently a very small field compared to software devs, or EE in general.  Andy Glew (@KrazyGlew on this site) has written a little bit about how he got into the field, being ["The SW / OS guy who knows about hardware", and vice versa"](https://www.linkedin.com/in/andyglew).  I think I remember reading more details from him, but a quick google didn't turn it up.  I think I've read that it's not an easy field to get into; people usually come into it after experience in other fields, either HW or SW or both.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, found him here http://blog.andy.glew.ca/. I am wondering why do guys like this need any account in LinkedIn?

Comment: Regarding 2), OS design is impacted by both cpu architecture and application requirements. An application that requires locking (modern many core multi-threaded applications) will demand OS support which in turn may demand (if locking is too expensive for OS which it is) CPU support. A CPU that supports low-power features will demand the OS to support it. (eg; A mobile phone CPU that shuts off certain core units on idle)

Comment: Following the above comment, for (1, and 3) application "pull" usually impacts frequents OS design changes. Further for (3), CPU architecture changes are very expensive and slow (5 years or more). Comparatively, applications change very rapidly (~weeks to months).